# Global variable data not passed [Godot.2.15]

Tags: godot, gdscript

I was creating a "Addition mental math calculator" in Godot ,where the user is shown a new question on hitting "on_Button_pressed" button and the  sum is stored in "global var c "and then the input is accessed via "Lineedit" and stored in "var d" .However ,when "var c" is passed for comparison with "var d" in "Lineedit",it passes a "Null" value .How could one pass values between two functions.

```
extends Panel

# global variables
var a = " "
var b = " "
var c = " "
var d = " "

func _ready():
    pass

#Generate Random number and store sum in "var c"    
func _on_Button_pressed():

    randomize()
    var a = floor (rand_range(1,100))
    var b = floor (rand_range(1,100))

    var c = a+b
    print (a)
    print (b)
    print ("c = "+ str(c))

    get_node("RichTextLabel").set_text(str(a)+"+"+str(b)+"=")



#User_input
func _on_LineEdit_text_entered( text ):
    d = get_node("LineEdit").text

#pass sum "var c" for comparison with user_input "var d" 

print(c)<-- NUll value being passed.


#Accesing value via node method
#   var e = get_node("Panel").get("c").to_float()<-- Error-"Panel node doesn't exist"
#   print(e)


#convert d to float 
    var f = d.to_float()
    print(f)

#Compare sum with user_input
#   if  f == c:
#       get_node("RichTextLabel").set_text("Right Answer")
#   else:
#       get_node("RichTextLabel").set_text("Wrong Answer")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Where and to which other function is your variable `c` passed? In `_on_LineEdit_text_entered` `c` is not used.

Comment: @Maximilian Peters  -var c (sum)is passed from _on_Button_pressed() to func_on_LineEdit_text_entered() for comparision with user_input var f(var d converted to float)  under  #Compare sum with user_input  ,The comparison is commented out () as on running the script it will result in an error and not display the values of the variables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
var c = a + b
```

With

```
c = a + b
```

The var c is declaring a new var working the scope of the function. The var keyword should be on the outermost declaration of the code.

Hope that helps!